# Concat nodes on Xpath

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I have the following html:

```
<td>

  <h1>Headline</h1><br>
  <strong>Subheadline</strong><br>

  Text1<br>
  Text2

  <h2>Subheadline2</h2>
  <div>stuff</div>
  <div>more stuff!</div>

</td>
```

I'm trying to grab "Text1" and "Text2". 
After experimenting with Xpath (DOMXPath using php), I've 
discovered that `"td/text()[2]"` matches Text1 
 and `"td/text()[3]"` matches Text2 
I want to somehow concat them using Xpath, is it possible?

I can't seem to find proper documentation for this anywhere. 
W3schools has some examples but this is really not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concat() function does what you're trying to do, I believe.  Something like `concat(/td/text()[2], /td/text()[3])` should work.

I cleaned up your HTML (made all the <br> tags <br/>) and was able to do it with the concat function in OxygenXML.

Comment: sadly i have no control over the HTML (it is what it is), plus i'm not sure if OxygenXML works like DOMXpath queries.

Comment: OxygenXML's parser definitely doesn't work like PHP's DOMDocument parser but that's ok.  What's important is that the concat function should be expected to work the same in both places!

Comment: i'm getting an empty DOMNodeList, eventhough /td/text()[2] and /td/text()[3] separately do give out content.

Comment: `DOMXPath::query()` only returns `DOMNodeList` objects.  You want a string.  `DOMXPath::evaluate()` is what you need.  

I suggest that you read over the `DOMXPath` docs at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) :).  Also check the documentation for `DOMDocument` as it's very useful.

Comment: this works very well, i switched to evaluate on all the other queries too

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be possible, haven't tested though.
From W3 docs - http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

```
fn:concat(string,string,...)
```

Returns the concatenation of the strings

Example: `concat('XPath ','is ','FUN!')`
Result: `'XPath is FUN!'`

Comment: w3schools is not the W3 docs, they are not affiliated with the W3C in any way. The XPATH W3 doc : http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/
A good read on w3schools : http://w3fools.com/

Comment: from w3 docs:  Function: string concat(string, string, string*)
The concat function returns the concatenation of its arguments. Isn't it the same? I'm using w3schools as a basic reference and I still had no problems with anything posted there. I don't like the way iformation listed in w3.org - too much words = too many time missed to get information. In learning purposes it is good, though